# Is webRtc support to show remote pc's video streaming and upload it into servr

Tags: webrtc

Is webRtc support to show remote pc's video streaming and upload it into server .

Flow Should be:

1. Get Clients pc's video streaming in the browser.
2. Upload this video into web server and track it for future suppose.

Answer (score 2):

MediaStreamRecorder is the best tool for that if you don't require realtime video. See [this sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/) which you need to modify (see the handleDataAvailable function) to upload the chunks (or the complete video) to a server.